# Issues with stop-losses in pinescript strategy. Probably a simple problem

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I'm trying to build my first tradingview strategy, think I'm doing pretty good considering I've been learning about it for less than a week. I'm actually having fun! Of course I've run into a lot of problems figuring it out as I go (and found a lot of solutions on this site, many thanks to those who answer questions!), but this time I think I'm really stuck and could use some advice.

The main issue is with my stop losses, they don't seem to be working at all and I'm out of ideas to try.  It's probably something stupidly simple and obvious. Also, it doesn't always fire a signal when the RSI lines cross while overbought/oversold like it should. It might be happening when the cross happens exactly at the candle close I'm not really sure, but that's less important. I'm less interested in making a perfect strategy as I am in building a framework I can plug different ideas into without having to start all over every time. Anyway if anyone has any ideas to try I would really REALLY appreciate it!

```
//@version=5
//optimized for BTCUSDT 30min TF

strategy("Chriscross_v5",
overlay=true,
precision=2,
pyramiding=0,
calc_on_every_tick=false,
calc_on_order_fills=true,
default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
default_qty_value=100,
initial_capital=10000,
commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
commission_value=0.015
)


// RSI
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1, group = "RSI Parameters")
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
rsi_index = input.int(21, 'RSI Index', 0, 100)
rsi_ob = k > 100 - rsi_index and d > 100 - rsi_index
rsi_os = k < rsi_index and d < rsi_index
rsi_crossdown = ta.crossunder(k, d)
rsi_crossup = ta.crossover(k, d)

// Parameters
tp1 = input.float(title=' Take profit1 %', defval=1.9, minval=0.01)
tp2 = input.float(title=' Take profit2 %', defval=3, minval=0.01)
q1 = input.int(title=' TP1 Quantity %', defval=100, minval=1)
q2 = input.int(title=' TP2 Quantity %', defval=50, minval=1)
sl = input.float(title=' stop loss %', defval=3, minval=0.01)
ep = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)

// Functions
per(pcnt) =>
strategy.position_size != 0 ? math.round(pcnt / 100.0 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na) //percent as points
//perc(pcnt) =>
//    strategy.position_size != 0 ? (pcnt / 100.0 + 1.0) * strategy.position_avg_price : float(na) //percent as price

// Colors
colorRed = #FF2052
colorGreen = #66FF00

// Date Range Filter
useDateFilter = input.bool(true, title="Filter Date Range of Backtest", group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("1 Jan 2022"), title="Start Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestEndDate = input.time(timestamp("1 Jan 2025"), title="End Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
inTradeWindow = not useDateFilter or (time >= backtestStartDate and time < backtestEndDate)


// ORDERS
// Check if strategy has open positions
inLong = strategy.position_size > 0
inShort = strategy.position_size < 0
// Check if strategy reduced position size in last bar
longClose = strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1]
shortClose = strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1]

// Entry Conditions
longCondition = rsi_os and rsi_crossup
shortCondition = rsi_ob and rsi_crossdown

// Exit Conditions
current_position_size = math.abs(strategy.position_size)
initial_position_size = math.abs(ta.valuewhen(strategy.position_size[1] == 0.0, strategy.position_size, 0))

longTP1 = strategy.position_avg_price + per(tp1) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)
longTP2 = strategy.position_avg_price + per(tp2) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)

shortTP1 = strategy.position_avg_price - per(tp1) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)
shortTP2 = strategy.position_avg_price - per(tp2) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)

// Calculate Stop Loss
// Initialise variables
var float longSL = 0.0
var float shortSL = 0.0

// When in a position, check to see if the position was reduced on the last bar
// If it was, set stop loss to position entry price. Otherwise, maintain last stop loss value
// When not in position, set stop loss using close price?
longSL := if inLong and ta.barssince(longClose) < ta.barssince(longCondition)
    strategy.position_avg_price - per(sl) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)
else if inLong
    longSL[1]
//else
//   close - longSL
shortSL := if inShort and ta.barssince(shortClose) < ta.barssince(shortCondition)
    strategy.position_avg_price + per(sl) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / math.abs(strategy.position_size)
else if inShort
    shortSL[1]
//else
//    close - shortSL

// Manage positions
if longCondition and inTradeWindow
    strategy.close("Short", comment="Exit Short")
    strategy.close("Long", comment="Exit Long")
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Enter Long")

if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit('TP1', from_entry='Long', qty_percent=q1, limit=longTP1, stop=longSL)
    strategy.exit('TP2', from_entry='Long', qty_percent=q1, limit=longTP1, stop=longSL)

if shortCondition and inTradeWindow
    strategy.close("Long", comment="Exit Long")
    strategy.close("Short", comment="Exit Short")
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Enter Short")

if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit('TP1', from_entry='Short', qty_percent=q1, limit=shortTP1, stop=shortSL)
    strategy.exit('TP2', from_entry='Short', qty_percent=q1, limit=shortTP1, stop=shortSL)

//draw
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na : ep, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na : ep, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), style=plot.style_linebr)


//indicator("Chriscross_B", overlay=false, precision=2)
//
////Levels
//bandno0 = (100 - rsi_index)
//bandno2 = (50)
//bandno1 = (rsi_index)
//
//h0 = hline(bandno0, 'Upper Band', color=#606060)
//h2 = hline(bandno2, 'Middle Band', color=#606060)
//h1 = hline(bandno1, 'Lower Band', color=#606060)
//fill(h0, h1, color=color.new(#9915FF, 80), title='Background')
//
//hline(100, "Max", color.red, hline.style_solid)
//hline(0, "Min", color.red, hline.style_solid)
//
// Stochastic Chart
//plot(k, 'K', color=color.new(#0094FF, 0), linewidth=2)
//plot(d, 'D', color=color.new(#FF6A00, 0), linewidth=1)
//
// Circles
//stOBOS = input.bool(true)
//plot(stOBOS ? rsi_crossdown and k >= bandno0 ? d : na : rsi_crossdown ? d : na, color=colorRed, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
//plot(stOBOS ? rsi_crossup and k <= bandno1 ? d : na : rsi_crossup ? k : na, color=colorGreen, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
```

"what have you tried before, and what did you expect?"

So many things!  My first version was much simpler and actually worked, but as the whole thing got more elaborate I lost it somewhere along the way. This is how I was doing it before.

```
// Entry and Exit

buy = stoch_rsi_os and ta.crossover(k, d)
sell = stoch_rsi_ob and ta.crossunder(k, d)

if buy and inTradeWindow
    strategy.close("Sell", comment="Exit Short")
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, comment="Enter Long")

if sell and inTradeWindow
    strategy.close("Buy", comment="Exit Long")
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, comment="Enter Short")

strategy.exit('x1', qty_percent=q1, profit=per(tp1), loss=per(los))
strategy.exit('x2', qty_percent=q2, profit=per(tp2), loss=0) // Moves SL to entry after TP1?  Not sure if this is right.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an if statement in a reassignment. You need to say if then reassign. You've also got a lot of unnecessary ' \'s

```
if inLong and ta.barssince(longClose) < ta.barssince(longCondition)
    longSL := whatever your stop loss should be
else if inLong
    longSL := longSL[1]
else
   longSL := close - longSL

if inShort and ta.barssince(shortClose) < ta.barssince(shortCondition)
    shortSL := whatever your short stop loss 
else if inShort
    shortSL := shortSL[1]
else
    shortSL :=  close - shortSL
```

Comment: This site added all those backslashes, been trying to go back and clean it all up. Also made me indent everything 4 spaces?  what a pain!  :(  Anyway thanks for the reply!

Comment: ah I see! well taking the if statement out of the reassignment variable should fix that for you at least

Comment: Well it makes sense and I'm sure that's the proper way to do it, but changing it didn't actually fix the problem.  It did point out another issue and I've removed two of the "strategy.close" lines because after applying your fix they were causing trades to exit immediately.  But for some reason trades still aren't getting stopped out when they should, Its rare they even get to the SL level but I've got a recent example where it should have stopped at 3%, but went all the way to 8% at the next reverse position signal.

Comment: guessing I'm probably just calculating the SL level wrong. still trying to figure out how to work with percents :)

Comment: Its done the same way as for calculating the TP, and those seem to work fine.  Except that I used ":="  instead of just "=", but I think that should be correct?

Comment: When you first declare it “=“ is fine but if you are reassigning the value you will want to use “:=“

Comment: Right that's what I thought, so that part is ok.   Rearranging that statement seems like it was a step in the right direction, but there's still something else going on that I'm missing.  I guess I could just go back to the earlier simpler version, but I won't learn anything that way.